# Why Does This Scanf Result in Infinite Loop?

Tags: c, loops, char, infinite-loop, scanf

So I've just started learning C for a class of mine, and I have been working on this assignment, but this part has me perplexed. I have some code that essentially looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int one = 0;
    int two = 0;
    char oneWord[100]; 
    char twoWord[100];

    printf("Enter a two digit number: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &one, &two);

    strcpy(firstWord, "Test");
    strcpy(secondWord, "Two");

    printf("%s", firstWord);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, logic/purpose of the program aside, what I cannot figure out is why that scanf statement is resulting in an infinite loop? I determined that was that cause of the problem when I commented it out and the final `printf` statement worked just fine.

I tried changing it to `scanf("%d,%d", %one, %two)` and that seemed to work fine when I added a comma to the input. But I want to just be able to take a number like 55 and break it into 2 digits. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read whole story. Change `%d` to `%c` to read only one character

Comment: Lol, literally just figured this out after posting the question. For my purposes, what worked was `scanf("%1d%1d", &one, &two)`.

Comment: How about separating the numbers in the input with a space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you run into is not an infinite loop, but rather `scanf` waiting for more input.

The `d`-format-specifier means a decimal number, so anything like "0", "41", or "2342345".

After you have entered the first number, **you** expect the program to continue, but `scanf` has just completed the first `%d`, so `scanf` is waiting for you to fulfill the second `%d`. This is what seems to you an infinite loop, but really is `scanf` doing what you ordered it to.

`scanf` cannot guess how many digits for each number you desire. But you can tell it how you want it, with a width-specifier that tells how many characters each information is composed of:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int a, b;
    scanf("%2d%1d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d, %d", a, b);
}
```

with error handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int a, b;
    if (scanf("%2d%1d", &a, &b) < 2)
        fprintf(stderr, "not enough digits");
    else
        printf("%d, %d", a, b);
}
```

Comment: Also tell him that it is not infinite loop. instead it is waiting for just one more number to be entered.

Comment: Ah man, didn't expect so many answers this fast! But what I ended up doing was `scanf("%1d%1d", &one, &two)`, is there any problem with doing that as opposed to your solution of `scanf("%2d%1d", &one, &two)`?

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer: You must understand what the digit before the `d` means: It is the number of digits to parse, so for "%3d" and the number "123456", `scanf` would give you "123". Now you should be able to answer your question yourself.

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer Welcome :) (edit: added a more detailed explanation for the "infinite loop")

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but `%d` means "an integer", not "a digit". So `55` is the first `%d`, then the second one isn't defined.

You could try with `%c` (one char).

Comment: You are probably right. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) for reference, but doesn't completely answer his question.

Comment: Also tell him that it is not infinite loop. instead it is waiting for just one more number to be entered.

Comment: To be more precise, "d" is for "decimal", meaning a "decimal number", in other words, a base 10 number.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Enter a two digit number: ");
scanf("%1d%1d", &one, &two);
```

Of course even this can fail (not meet the requirements)
Instead:

```
scanf("%d", &one);
if (one<10 || one>99) printf("I didn't expect that...\n");
```

or

```
scanf("%s",oneWord); one = atoi(oneWord);
if (one<10 || one>99)
   printf("Thats not necessarily even a number\n");
else
   { two = one % 10; one = one / 10; 
       printf("The first digit is %d and the second is %d\n",one,two);
   }
```

In the latter program we are testing that the input is correct:
It's a good practice to feed garbage instead of the correct input and see, where it goes unnoticed. The library function atoi(string); returns an integer contained in a string. It's zero, if no integer was found. e.g. (atoi("a1") == 0).

But the minimum correct answer would be

```
scanf("%d", number);
if (number >= 10 && number <= 99) 
{
   one = number / 10;  // the first digit;
   two = number % 10;  // the second digit calculated as number modulo 10
}

scanf("%1d%d", &one, &two);  // would halt for a single character input
```

Comment: if `one` is a single, decimal (as in "d") digit, then how could it be bigger than 9? And an error check that is itself unsure about what it does is not a valid error check.

Comment: Try the first example and enter e.g. 123; it's not a two digit number.

Comment: I missed that you don't use a width-specifier in your second format string (unlike in the first format string). However, it wouldn't solve the questioners problem of dissecting a number string into several numbers. Also: Your second example goes a bit too far for the problem at hand. Maybe at least explain what you are doing there?